# Compositional data: is it possible to make products of components/features in a composition?

Tags: interaction, data-transformation, ecology, compositional-data

I've never asked about Stack OverFlow, even though it's been so useful to me on many occasions! I'm sorry if this topic has already been discussed previously, perhaps I wasn't able to find the good keywords. Also, you should know that English is not my native language, so I apologize if my formulations are not very correct.

Anyway, my question is about the handling of composition data. I'm fundamentally a biologist, thus I'm not totally at ease dealing with the world of compositional data - a fascinating world !

*I will give you two versions of my question: a very direct version **(1)**, and a detailed and contextualized version **(2)**.*

**(1) Short version of my question:**
Is it possible to make products of components within a composition (previously divided by its total amount) ?

If it is possible, is it necessary to perform a log-ratio transformation first and which one (ALR, CLR, ILR)? - although I am aware that there is no gold standard of transformation, maybe one of this one would be suite to perform products of components.

**(2) Long version of my question:**
Let me give you a brief background to illustrate the origin of my question. My goal is to identify planktonic species that are associated with each other, potentially interacting ecologically. To do this, one of the basic practices in ecology is to look for planktonic species that are *correlated* with each other, across samples.

To do this, I have a counting table with the samples in rows and the planktonic species in columns.

However, this count table does not contain absolute counts since each sample (i.e. each row here) constitutes a composition - hence the relative counts.

So I have N samples for N distinct compositions.

But my compositions are not conventional in the sense that they are very sparse (many 0 values - and for this reason I must apply a pseudocount before doing LR transformations) and the total amount of each composition is not fixed and can vary a lot.

As you may know, correlation is deprecated with respect to compositional data.
From the literature, I found that a better solution would be to apply an LR transformation, and use proportionality measures instead of correlations to identify dependent components. Maybe an opinion of this even if it is not my main question ?

Once I have done this, I report pairs of planktonic species that have "good proportionality", so I deal with pairwise combinations of planktonic species, or pairwise components.

Then, for each pair of planktonic species - or pair of components, I want to calculate scores *in each sample* so N scores, each of those scores reflecting some sort of probability that the planktonic species might be able to interact with each other in that sample. Hypothetically, the more abundant each of these species is, the more likely they are to interact.

And to do this, a very naive approach that comes to mind would be to multiply them, roughly, after dividing each composition by its total amount.

But, I'm not sure I'm allowed to do that when dealing with compositions although I read a lot of literature (I don't have a mathematical background so it's not instinctive for me).

If someone could help me to shed light on this, I would be grateful ! Thanks.

Comment: Re the short version: of course.  You just multiply.  What is needed for any deeper answer is a better sense of the statistical nature of your data and the model(s) you are contemplating using.

Comment: You say "the total amount of each composition is not fixed and can vary a lot." Do you have that "total amount of each composition" information available so that you could reconstruct the original counts? Working with count data is generally preferable to working with fractional measures, as the reliability of an estimated fraction depends on the total number of cases examined.